# Why is $\phi(pq) \neq pq-4$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, prime-numbers, totient-function

I currently am seeing that if $p$ and $q$ are primes, that $\phi(pq) = pq-4$ and am wondering what I am doing wrong. First, I see that if a number $d$ is greater than $1$ and divides $pq$, then it must be a multiple of either $p$ or $q$- because $pq=dk$ for some integer $k$, and the prime factorization for $pq$ and $dk$ must be equivalent, so at least one of $p$ or $q$ must be in the prime factorization for $d$. Then, I see that if $d=pl$ for some integer $l$, then $k$ must be $q$, because if $k$ isn't $q$, then $pq=kd=kpl$ implies $q=kl$, which is impossible as $q$ is prime. Therefore the only numbers which divide $pq$ are $p,q,pq,1$, so $\phi(pq) = pq-4$. What have I done wrong?

Comment: The definition of Euler totient function $\varphi(n)$ is not $n$ minus the number of divisors of $n$; if it were, the answer would indeed be $pq-4$.

Comment: It helps to look at a concrete case, like $p = 2$, $q = 5$. There are 10 numbers in the list $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10$. Some are counted by $\phi$ and some are not. It helps if you start by crossing out all the ones that are *not* counted by $\phi$ and see who  is left. You are right that 2, 5 and 10 should be kicked out. About 1 we can have a small discussion. But then there are others that also don't make the cut...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented, $pq$ takeaway the number of divisors of $pq$ is not the definition of $\phi(pq)$. We care about the number of integers between $1$ and $pq$ *coprime* to $pq$. It’s a reasonable mistake to think this is just about divisors, but this is wrong. Let’s take $p=3,q=5$. Now, $10$ does not divide $pq=15$ but it is not coprime to $15$ either; they share a common factor of $5$. Therefore we do *not* count $10$ in $\phi(15)$. So you need to include such cases in your calculation.

You should get $\phi(pq)=(p-1)(q-1)$.

Comment: In general if $p$ is a prime then $\phi(p) = p-1$

Answer (score 0):

Being coprime to $pq$ is not the same as not being a divisor of $pq$.

It is true that if $m>1$ is coprime to $pq$, then $m$ cannot be a divisor of $pq$. However, $1$ is both coprime to and a divisor of $pq$. Also, the converse is not true. For $1 < n < q$, $pn$ is neither coprime to nor a divisor of $pq$. Likewise, for $1 < n < p$, $nq$ is again neither coprime to nor a divisor of $pq$.

So, the correct value of $\phi(pq)$ is not $pq-4$ but rather $pq-3-(p-2)-(q-2) = pq-3-p+2-q+2 = pq-p-q+1$.